# How convert result of linq query to List(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, list, knockout.js

I'm using EntityFrameWork 5 in VB MV4 project.

I have a database built from EntityFramework diagram (model firt as opposed to code first)

I have a ViewModel X, containing a List(ofT)  T being one on my Entity

When I open my web application (on the browser) I ask a controller to give me the ViewModel X as a Json object that I use to populate a MVVC (knockout model) using the Knockout JS Mapping pluggin.

When I ask for the model, I populate it using code similar to what is shown below

```vb
Public Class DataServiceController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    <Authorize()> _
    Public Function RetrieveData() As JsonResult

        Dim model As ViewModelX
        model = New ViewModelX

    '=====================================
    ' Resources and Tools
    '=====================================
    Dim fetchedResourceAndToolsQuery = From a In db.ResourceAndTools
                       Where a.ProfileId = profile.ProfileId Select a

    For Each eachRes In fetchedResourceAndToolsQuery
        Dim res As ResourceAndTools = New ResourceAndTools
        res.Name = Trim(eachRes.Name)
        res.URL = Trim(eachRes.URL)
        res.Target = eachRes.Target
        res.ResourceId = eachRes.ResourceId
        model.ResourceAndTools.Add(res)
    Next

    Return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Everthing works great! Except... And here's the question

As mentionned above, ViewModelX contains a List(of T) T being *ResourceAndTools*

Is there a was to copy (clone, load, not sure of the term) the content of fetchedResourceAndToolsQuery (Result of the Linq Query) to model.ResourceAndTools (List(of T)) without instantiating a new object and copying the properties like I'm doing.

I've seached (Cloning, Deep Copying, Shallow Copying, etc.)  The closest I came to a solution was some explanation on how to deep copy an object but it relied on serialisation, it did not work because not all properties of a Entity Framework object are serialisable.

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `fetchedResourceAndToolsQuery.ToList()` ?

Comment: You can deserialise the JSON directly in a list.

Comment: Why don't you modify the entities template to make all entities serializable ?

Comment: Damien:  I don't want to modify each entites because they are generated by the Entity Framework.  I'm using the model first approach, not code first approach.  Modifying the entities is not an option.

Comment: Yuriy: Yes, I have tried that and it does not work.

Comment: Nadeem:  I seem like not all properties of the entities are serialisable.  Any attempt I made using serialisation failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
model.ResourceAndTools = (
    From a In db.ResourceAndTools
    Where a.ProfileId = profile.ProfileId
    Select New ResourceAndTools() With { _
        .Name = Trim(a.Name), _
        .URL = Trim(a.URL), _
        .Target = a.Target, _
        .ResourceId = a.ResourceId}).ToList()
```

---

Following your comment, perhaps you could do,

```
Dim dataList = (
    From a In db.ResourceAndTools
    Where a.ProfileId = profile.ProfileId
    Select New With
    {
        .Name = Trim(a.Name),
        .URL = Trim(a.URL),
        .Target = a.Target,
        .ResourceId = a.ResourceId
    }).ToList()

model.ResourceAndTools = dataList.ConvertAll(Function(data)
        Return New ResourceAndTools() With
        {
            .Name = data.Name,
            .Url = data.Url,
            .Target = data.Target,
            .ResourceId = data.ResourceId
        }
    End Function)
```

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer. Two questions:  1- Performance wise, Is this much better than what I do already? 2- Can you explain where eachRes come from.  I'm trying to test the code you suggested me but I can't figure out how to declare eachRes?

Comment: Forget my previous comment.  I was about to figure out your example.  I replaced eachRes by "a.".  Unfortunatetly I get to following exception

'OptimaxModel.ResourceAndTools' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query'

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry for late response, the solution provided works, thank you, I find it more elegant then looping true the Linq.IQueryable object.  Although I was hoping for a solution where I would not have to assign each field individually but rather a solution that would use reflection to find the properties and copy them.  From a maintenance perspective, it would be better not have to worry about the code should the model change.  Since Entity Framework generates the model, it would be nice if the copying was done transparently.

Comment: BTW, I'm new this forum, how can I accept the answer?  Is it important that I accept the answer?